# Emerald Greens trimming

Tags: pruning, tree-care, growth

When is it to late to in the year trim emerald greens in Seattle? I don't want to hamper their ability to recover before winter.

Comment: Are you asking about lawns or arborvitae, cedar?

Comment: Clarification as to what plant you're referring to please - there's  a Hebe variety named Emerald Green, and I believe it might be a common name in the USA for cedar... as well as, possibly, grass.

Comment: Not grass, Emerald Green Arborvitae. Thanks.

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Terry I apologize.  That was one of the silliest, lamest of my bloopers ever.  How is the weather up there?  We have been gone 6 years and I miss Washington!  Oregon used to be a cool state but not anymore!

Answer (score 1):

You've confirmed you're talking about Emerald Green arborvitae, and yes, it is a bit late, or early, depending on when you choose to prune back. You can trim them back in December, when they're dormant, or in spring, just as growth begins. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/time-trim-arborvitaes-48215.html

Comment: Feetsies in mouth.  I can't believe I never even thought about the arborvitaes...I went right to Emerald Downs Horse Racing.

Comment: @stormy So, doing a good impression of a runaway horse yourself then!

Comment: exactly my sad drift...grins?

Comment: Well, its not the end of the world - but maybe wait, read properly,, consider and think at the starting gate before sprinting off in future;-)

Comment: Oh Bamboo, that would take away my allure!  I will never be so wonderfully organized.  Those that make mistakes learn from them.

Comment: Well we've all made mistakes, including me - I'm not a robot you know! its not the mistakes that count,  its the learning from them that's important - you've just said you're not going to because its part of your allure! Which presumably means you prefer to keep on making mistakes... oh well, each to his own I guess

Comment: I make sure I learn from my mistakes, are you kidding?  Surely, you don't believe that about me, Bamboo?  I am involved in life and I make my share of mistakes because I am not overly concerned about making mistakes.  I am just embroiled in learning and testing and thinking and gee, I do make repeats but not that often.  This forum is impossible to be so correct all the time.  I don't know how you do so well, honest.  I miss the hands on aspect, this internet answer question stuff is tough.  Sigh.

Comment: @stormy - I've made mistakes on here - not many, admittedly, I'm just one of those unusual people with an affinity for words - I read every single one on the page, twice, to get the meaning straight, then sit and think before doing anything. Boring, I know, but I can't help it, I've got the mind of a researcher and a proof reader... spelling mistakes jump off the page at me.It can be very tiresome!

Comment: Huggs, you don't have 15 dang cats, 2 huge dogs, 2 big horses, a gnarly parrot, umpteen bunnies and live in DRUG  boonies.  You are not ADD.  Your life is organized and sensible.  Your water doesn't go out every other day.  You don't use an outhouse 300 feet away, or keep a fire going all night. 100 degrees every day but below freezing at night for at least a third of those days.  I am geared for adaptation, not organization. Trying to share my experience and knowledge based on limited information, comes with a few boo boos. You are the kind of partner I would choose, Yin to my Yang...